# why doesn't my bi-cubic interpolation work?

Tags: c#, math, smoothing

I have an 2d float Array called "Altitude" (just random values from 0 to 1 for the time being)
I want to generate 1 tile of smooth terrain per Altitude sample using bicubic interpolation.

I am using the following method to do the math:

```
    private float CubicPolate(float v0, float v1, float v2, float v3, float position)
    {
        float A = (v3 - v2) - (v0 - v1);
        float B = (v0 - v1) - A;
        float C = v2 - v0;
        float D = v1;

        return A * Mathf.Pow(position, 3) + B * Mathf.Pow(position, 2) + C * position + D;
    }
```

Then I am creating the vertices for each tile with the draw method (For simplicity I've omitted parts related to defining triangles, normals and UVs):

```
private void draw(int xCoord, int yCoord)
    {
        List<Vector3> newVerts = new List<Vector3>();

        float[,] ndata = new float[4, 4];
        for (int X = 0; X < 4; X++)
            for (int Y = 0; Y < 4; Y++)
                ndata[X, Y] = Altitude[xCoord + (X - 1), yCoord + (Y - 1)];

        for (int x = 0; x <= resolution; x++)
        {
            float fracx = x / resolution;
            float x1 = CubicPolate(ndata[0, 0], ndata[1, 0], ndata[2, 0], ndata[3, 0], fracx);
            float x2 = CubicPolate(ndata[0, 1], ndata[1, 1], ndata[2, 1], ndata[3, 1], fracx);
            float x3 = CubicPolate(ndata[0, 2], ndata[1, 2], ndata[2, 2], ndata[3, 2], fracx);
            float x4 = CubicPolate(ndata[0, 3], ndata[1, 3], ndata[2, 3], ndata[3, 3], fracx);

            for (int y = 0; y <= resolution; y++)
            {
                float fracy = y / resolution;
                newVerts.Add(new Vector3(fracx, CubicPolate(x1, x2, x3, x4, fracy), fracy));
            }
        }

        Mesh newMesh = new Mesh();
        newMesh.vertices = newVerts.ToArray();
        meshFilters[xCoord, yCoord].mesh = newMesh;
    }
```

Everything I've read says that this should work. But the resulting tiles of terrain have straight lines between the four corners irrespective of how many vertices make up the mesh. Its like its using linear interpolation. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If `resolution` is an integer, you will get integer division for `x/resolution` and `y/resolution` - this will almost always be zero. Only the last one will be 1.

Comment: @Nico  OMG, that's all it was! Thanks!